# How to access a specific context in ember 1.0 pre with action helper

Tags: ember.js

In my ember view I want to get the person during this each and have it passed to the action but currently I only get a jquery event in the router (curious if this is bound to the context for free in pre 1.0 now)

template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
       {{#each person in controller}}
          <li> 
          {{person.username}}
          <input type="submit" value="delete" {{action removePerson person}}/>                   
          </li>
       {{/each}}
</script>
```

router w/ the method I was hoping to invoke w/ the person context

```
Router: Ember.Router.create({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      removePerson: function(router, context) {
        router.get('personController').removePerson(context);
      },
```

controller in more detail

```
PersonController: Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      content: [],                                                                               
      addPerson: function (username) {
        var person = PersonApp.Person.create({
          username: username
        });
        this.pushObject(person);
      },
      removePerson: function (person) {
        this.removeObject(person);
      }
    }),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second variable passed to the router action handler is actually the event. The context is a variable of this event. Rewrite it like so:

```
Router: Ember.Router.create({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      removePerson: function(router, event) {
        router.get('personController').removePerson(event.context);
      },
```

Comment: thank you! (not sure why I didn't see this initially when I dropped into the debugger)

Comment: one last question -unrelated I know. If I was doing this w/ full persistence would the router invoke a simple DELETE via http async first then kick off the removePerson event on the controller to make the app look like it's happening real-time. If not how should I approach this going forward?

Comment: If are using ember-data then your removePerson method should create a transaction, add the record to the transaction, call deleteRecord, and then transaction.commit(). A successful commit will remove the record from the collection automatically.

Comment: Awesome -I hope to see ember-data included in the official v1.0 release (currently I'm not actually using it so I'll need to read up)